# How do I catch SocketExceptions in MonkeyRunner?

Tags: jython, monkeyrunner

When using MonkeyRunner, every so often I get an error like:

```
120830 18:39:32.755:S [MainThread] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] Unable to get variable: display.density
120830 18:39:32.755:S [MainThread] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

From what I've read, sometimes the adb connection goes bad, and you need to reconnect. The only problem is, I'm not able to catch the `SocketException`. I'll wrap my code like so:

```
try:
    density = self.device.getProperty('display.density')
except:
    print 'This will never print.'
```

But the exception is apparently not raised all the way to the caller. I've verified that MonkeyRunner/jython can catch Java exceptions the way I'd expect:

```
>>> from java.io import FileInputStream
>>> def test_java_exceptions():
...     try:
...         FileInputStream('bad mojo')
...     except:
...         print 'Caught it!'
...
>>> test_java_exceptions()
Caught it!
```

How can I deal with these socket exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the workaround I ended up using. Any function that can suffer from adb failures just needs to use the following decorator:

```
from subprocess import call, PIPE, Popen
from time import sleep

def check_connection(f):
    """
    adb is unstable and cannot be trusted.  When there's a problem, a
    SocketException will be thrown, but caught internally by MonkeyRunner
    and simply logged.  As a hacky solution, this checks if the stderr log 
    grows after f is called (a false positive isn't going to cause any harm).
    If so, the connection will be repaired and the decorated function/method
    will be called again.

    Make sure that stderr is redirected at the command line to the file
    specified by config.STDERR. Also, this decorator will only work for 
    functions/methods that take a Device object as the first argument.
    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            cmd = "wc -l %s | awk '{print $1}'" % config.STDERR
            p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
            (line_count_pre, stderr) = p.communicate()
            line_count_pre = line_count_pre.strip()

            f(*args, **kwargs)

            p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
            (line_count_post, stderr) = p.communicate()
            line_count_post = line_count_post.strip()

            if line_count_pre == line_count_post:
                # the connection was fine
                break
            print 'Connection error. Restarting adb...'
            sleep(1)
            call('adb kill-server', shell=True)
            call('adb start-server', shell=True)
            args[0].connection = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

    return wrapper
```

Because this may create a new connection, you need to wrap your current connection in a Device object so that it can be changed. Here's my Device class (most of the class is for convenience, the only thing that's necessary is the `connection` member:

```
class Device:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
        self.width = int(self.connection.getProperty('display.width'))
        self.height = int(self.connection.getProperty('display.height'))
        self.model = self.connection.getProperty('build.model')

    def touch(self, x, y, press=MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP):
        self.connection.touch(x, y, press)
```

An example on how to use the decorator:

```
@check_connection
def screenshot(device, filename):
    screen = device.connection.takeSnapshot()
    screen.writeToFile(filename + '.png', 'png')
```

Comment: Well, I have to said that is not due to an `adb` instability but MonkeyRuner/Chimpchat ones. [AndroidViewclient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) uses a `adbclient`, a python module that encapsulates all the dialog with `adb` and it's pretty stable.

Answer (score 8):

You will get that error every odd time you start MonkeyRunner because the `monkey --port 12345` command on the device isn't stopped when your script stops. It is a bug in monkey.

A nicer way to solve this issue is killing monkey when `SIGINT` is sent to your script (when you `ctrl+c`). In other words: `$ killall com.android.commands.monkey`.

Quick way to do it:

```py
from sys, signal
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

device = None

def execute():
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
    # your code

def exitGracefully(self, signum, frame=None):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT))
    device.shell('killall com.android.commands.monkey')
    sys.exit(1)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exitGracefully)
    execute()
```

Edit:
as an addendum, I also found a way to notice the Java errors: [Monkey Runner throwing socket exception broken pipe on touuch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416663/monkey-runner-throwing-socket-exception-broken-pipe-on-touuch/28070375#28070375)

Edit:
The signal seems to require 2 parameters, not sure it's always the case, made the third optional.